# How to load session data before stateProvider state changes in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, acl, synchronous

I'm using angular-acl (https://github.com/mikemclin/angular-acl)  to manage the authorization logic of my application and It's working fine, except when the user open a new window/tab.

When the user open a new window/tab I cannot access the sessionStorage so I need to reload the acl and the user roles from the API, but as the request is asynchronous it normally resolves after the check for permission.

How can I certify that the stateProvider only will change the page after the acl list is loaded?

Here is how I'm trying to reload the permission:

```
myApp.run(['AclService', 'Auth', '$http', function (AclService, Auth, $http) {
    if(!AclService.resume()) {
      Auth.load_acl();
      Auth.load_user_roles();
      // I need to certify that these requests are complete before continue
    }
}]);
```

The service that make the request:

```
var authServices = angular.module('authServices', []);

authServices.factory('Auth', ['$http', 'AclService', function($http, AclService) {
    var authService = {};

    authService.load_acl = function() {
        return $http.get('/auth/get_acl').then(function(response){
            var aclData = {};
            for(i in response.data) {
                var role = response.data[i];
                if(aclData[role.name] === undefined) 
                    aclData[role.name] = [];
                aclData[role.name].push(role.ability_name);
            }
            AclService.setAbilities(aclData);
        });
    };

    authService.load_user_roles = function() {
        return $http.get('/auth/get_user_roles').then(function(response){
            for(role in response.data) {
                AclService.attachRole(response.data[role]);
            }
        });
    };

    return authService;
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use state/route resolver:

```
...
resolve: {
  auth: function (AclService, Auth, $q) {
    if(!AclService.resume()) {
      return $q.all([Auth.load_acl(), Auth.load_user_roles());
    }
  }
}
```

Wrap it into separate service if you need to reuse it.